# select_tag rails question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select_tag, that is like this: 
Select something
something 1
something 2
...

After I chose something 2 and hit the submit button, it refreshes the page, but on the select_tag it shows Select something again. How can I make it show something 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on how you are displaying the select tag, but if you are using options_for_select you can do this:

```
@selected = params[:selected]

select_tag :selected, options_for_select([["Something 1", 1], ["Something 2", 2]], @selected)
```

This will tell the options for select to use @selected as the selected value.

Comment: There is a missing `[` before `["Something 1`