# Rails select_tag, options_for_select not showing selected option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

Running into odd behavior with the [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) helper here.

I have the following code:

```
= select_tag :mode, options_for_select([['Advanced Mode',true],['Basic Mode',false]], false)
```

I'm using `false` here instead of a variable, because it hasn't been working. Even with the above code, I can never get `Basic Mode` to be selected when the page loads.

I feel like I must be spacing out and missing an obvious typo or something, but looking at the documentation and [other questions on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786047/select-tag-rails-question) I don't see anything wrong with me code. What am I overlooking?

---

Update, even stranger... when I add the outer parens it works:

```
= select_tag(:mode, options_for_select(...))
```

Comment: Hmm not sure if true|false are usable words.. Try using them as strings? `options_for_select([['Advanced Mode', 'true'], ['Basic Mode', 'false']], 'false')`

Comment: Just tried that, no difference.

Comment: Have you tried with integers?

Comment: Just tried, still no difference. Seriously what the heck is going on here...

Comment: Oh snap! This is even stranger, updating question with new behavior.

Comment: MrYoshi, with outer parens on it starts working. I have no idea why it should matter, there's no other code on this line. Do you see something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Oh! I heard that Rails hates calls without the () around the parameters. I never thought it would cause this problem, but very strange behavior you found here!

Comment: It looks like you're using either HAML or SLIM. That's probably why it starts working with the added set of parentheses. If you tried the same bit of code in an ERB file, it'd probably work fine.

Comment: @samullen I've found this behavior all over Rails. I'm pretty sure it's a Ruby thing. As a general rule, I always wrap calls in parentheses if I'm passing in a parenthesized argument, such as `options_for_select` to `select_tag`.

Comment: @gg_s I've tested this in ERB, HAML, and Slim, everything works fine as originally coded above. If you are using either HAML, or Slim, is it possible that you have a badly indented block of code?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it must have been something like that. Now that I've fixed the problem, even I can't seem to duplicate it. I don't know what was really wrong.

Comment: I was having essentially the same problem but using form.select, and also using HAML. Putting outer parens solved the problem for me, thanks!